# (Acumatica) New row button on grid not working

Tags: acumatica

I created a custom screen in Acumatica. I have a simple table and a grid to add records to it.  The Account Mapping grid works (and it is way more complicated).  But on the Branch Mapping grid, when I click the “PLUS” icon, the icon goes grey and no new row is available on the grid.

[image]

This is what is looks like after clicking the PLUS icon:

[image]

The table is very simple.

[image]

When a Company is selected, the view for the grid is

```
       public SelectFrom<ICSBranchMapping>
        .Where<ICSBranchMapping.organizationID
            .IsEqual<ICSSetup.organizationID.FromCurrent>>.View BranchMapping;
```

The ICSSetup table is even simpler:

[image]

If I create a new record in ICSSetup, it lets me add 1 row to the ICSBranchMapping table

[image]

But I cannot add another row.

Here is the DAC for the ICSBranchMapping table

[image]

The records in the DB all look fine after adding the 1 row it will allow me to enter.

The action button is a dummy.  The code has been commented out to ensure it has nothing to do with the issue.

I forgot to mention, I CAN update the existing row.

I’ve been fighting with this for 2 days.  If anyone has any suggestions, please help.

Comment: Try setting the height of the grid to a larger number. Seems like the line is actually created but the height is too small to show it.

Comment: That is exactly what I think is happening.  I can add rows even though I cannot see them if I pretend the row is there.  It will actually let me save multiple rows even though they don't show on the screen.  I have Adjust Page Size = Auto, Height = 100%, Skin ID = Details.  I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I added the BranchMapping grid using the customization editor.

It did not include this line in the aspx:

That fixed it.  It seems like that should be a default in the Screen Editor.